# lateinit property homeViewModel has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, imageview

I have a problem, I added three textView (textView, textView2, textView3) and imageView to **fragment_home.xml** and when I try to run the application on the emulator in Android Studio I get the error **lateinit property homeViewModel has not been initialized**.

homeFragment.kt

```
class homeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: homeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(homeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

error log

```
6728-6728/com.radex.mysummercarmanual E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.radex.mysummercarmanual, PID: 6728
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property homeViewModel has not been initialized
        at com.radex.mysummercarmanual.ui.home.homeFragment.onCreateView(homeFragment.kt:23)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2466)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1483)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Most likely the story here is not complete, you will need to show more code, how are you creating your fragment?

Comment: Unrelated, but your class names should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try initialise your viewModel inside `onActivityCreated()`
- Don't observe or initiate you ViewModel inside `onCreateView()`
- Rename your class name from `homeFragment` to `HomeFragment` and `homeViewModel` to `HomeViewModel`
- You don't need to do findViewMyId in Kotlin. you can access view directly ID.
- The change Idea is bellow

  ```
  class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

  private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

  override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater,
      container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
      val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
      return root
  }


  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
      homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
      homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
          text_home.text = it
      })
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: I’m new to Android development—why do we want to keep the ViewModel initiation out of onCreateView()?  Google’s own training apps, such as https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-starter-apps/blob/master/RecyclerViewClickHandler-Starter/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepTrackerFragment.kt, have it there.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize `homeViewModel`, you reference an uninitialized one so it gives you the error.

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(***homeViewModel***::class.java)
```

I think the class name of your ViewModel should be `HomeViewModel`, so try this one:

```
private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

...

homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `code`, as you're inside fragment do not `initialize` *ViewModel* inside `onCreateView()`, simply means let the view create first then initilalize `viewModel`.
To initialize `viewModel` you have to override **onActivityCreated()** method and initialize viewModel inside it. Your code will be like this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState) 
    homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
    homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
        text_home.text = it
    })
}
```

And notice here i pass `activity!!` rather than `this`, cause you just can't get the activity context or getActivity() directly whenever you're inside the fragment just by calling `this`. You have to tell manually. So your `viewModel` instantiation will be like this:

```
homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
```

Or You could use `if` block, like this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    if(!::homeViewModel.isInitialized){ 
    homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
    homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
        text_home.text = it
    })
 }
}
```